# Mvn cannot install Jetty

Tags: macos, maven, jetty, maven-plugin, maven-jetty-plugin

My pom file:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.vivek.jersey.sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>vivek-jersey-sample</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>vivek-jersey-sample Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>vivek-jersey-sample</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty­maven­plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.11.v20150529</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Not when i do `mvn jetty:run` i get error saying it can't find `jetty` .I manually checked the urls.They seem valid.Also i tried with many many versions.All fail with same error.Can i configure `jetty` manually? Or is there any other server we can use?

`Exception`:

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.jetty:jetty­maven­plugin:jar:9.2.11.v20150529 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.eclipse.jetty:jetty­maven­plugin:9.2.11.v20150529: Plugin org.eclipse.jetty:jetty­maven­plugin:9.2.11.v20150529 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.eclipse.jetty:jetty­maven­plugin:jar:9.2.11.v20150529 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (13 kB at 6.2 kB/s)
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (20 kB at 8.1 kB/s)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.233 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-10T23:46:57+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/310M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'jetty' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/vks/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found for prefix 'jetty' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/vks/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:93)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.findPluginForPrefix(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:266)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:220)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:89)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

Comment: what happens when you run `touch /tmp/jetty.jar && mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.eclipse.jetty  -DartifactId=jetty-maven-plugin -Dversion=9.2.11.v20150529 -Dfile=/tmp/jetty.jar -Dpackaging=jar`

Comment: @Raphael `The POM for org.eclipse.jetty:jetty­maven­plugin:jar:9.2.11.v20150529 is missing, no dependency information available
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.eclipse.jetty:jetty­maven­plugin:9.2.11.v20150529: Plugin org.eclipse.jetty:jetty­maven­plugin:9.2.11.v20150529 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.eclipse.jetty:jetty­maven­plugin:jar:9.2.11.v20150529 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced`

Comment: try `wget https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-maven-plugin/9.2.11.v20150529/jetty-maven-plugin-9.2.11.v20150529.pom`

Comment: @Raphael m on mac so `curl "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-maven-plugin/9.2.11.v20150529/jetty-maven-plugin-9.2.11.v20150529.pom"` did work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plugin definition has an incorrect `<artifactId>`.

Use the proper one instead:

```xml
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty­-maven-­plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.5.v20170502</version>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Silly mistake.I copied content from pdf to vi and somehow `-` was not there.Thanx